# Locking a remote host in pool of hosts

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose I have a pool of hosts in a file somewhere

hosts.txt:

```
hosta@domain
hostb@domain
hostc@domain
```

I would like to be able to lock a host (something like flock /tmp/lockfile) so that other programs can't use that host. I would like to accomplish this with a bash script which iterates over the list of hosts, ssh'es into that host, tries to flock /tmp/lockfile on that machine, and if successful, returns with the name of the host. If unsuccessful, maybe it could return with some error code.

Currently, I have something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
USER=someuser
while read host; do
    echo -n "Trying ${host}..."
    xterm -e "ssh \"${USER}@${host}\" 'flock -n /tmp/lockfile -c \"echo Locked $host; read\"'" &
    FLOCK_PID=$!
    sleep 1
    kill -0 $FLOCK_PID;
    if [ ! $? ]; then
        echo -n "${host}"
        exit 0
    fi
done <hosts.txt
exit 1
```

This works but there are a few deficiencies. Because of the read command the only way I can think of to not block the shell is to start an xterm. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish what I want?

Comment: why do you use `xterm -e` ?

Comment: Because `read` is the command to flock is the only way I know to keep that file locked and read keeps the calling shell from proceeding until some input is provided.

Comment: I'll be honest, I can't really figure out what you're trying to do here. What do you mean by "other programs can't use the host"? What other programs might be "using" the host, and how would they be doing that?

Comment: Well, the host is a shared resource. I don't want multiple independent programs ssh'ing into the host and thrashing with each other. The use case is that we have n jobs and m hosts that those n jobs can run on. Each of them will independently execute the above script, the script will try to find an available host, lock it, and then inform the calling job which machine it should run on.